# How to display Bootstrap icons in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, fonts, icons, visual-studio-2022, glyph

I'm new to Xamarin development, but try to be exact.

Using Visual Studio 2022, with Xamarin version 17.0.0.182 (as displayed in VS About).

Found [this great article](https://doumer.me/using-bootstrap-and-material-font-icons-in-xamarin-forms/) on how to use Bootstrap icons, but it seems to be out of date. When I followed the steps and provided hex codes for the characters, I didn't get the expected glyiphs.

Answer (score 1):

I found that

- new Xamarin needs new methods,
- new Bootstrap fonts need new ways.

Here they are.

1.) Get the font from the Bootstrap github repo at https://github.com/twbs/icons

Go to releases (https://github.com/twbs/icons/releases), choose latest, scroll down to Assets, download the bootstrap-icons-x.x.x.xip file.

Unzip it, and find fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff.

Not something you can use in Xamarin right away :-(

2.) Convert the woff file to ttf

I googled for a converter and used https://cloudconvert.com/woff-to-ttf

Now you have the ttf you need :-)

3.) Now follow the current Xamarin method of adding a font to your app.

The process is described here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/

In short:

- add the ttf file to the shared Xamarin project, Embedded Resources / Fonts
- change file properties / Build Action to "Embedded resource"
- register the font by adding a line to the end of Assemblyinfo.cs:
  [assembly: ExportFont("bootstrap-icons.ttf", Alias = "Bootstrap")]

4.) Use it in xaml like

```
   <Label FontFamily="Bootstrap" Text="&#xf62c;"/>
```

to display a magnifying glass.

You may also define a Label style, but I'll skip that for now.

4/b.) To use it in xaml via binding

Oh, if things were easy...

When using a binding to display a glyph, there's one more hoop to jump, thanks to these guys for the solution: [Using data binding, how do I bind text which contains emojis to a label and have it display correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328197/using-data-binding-how-do-i-bind-text-which-contains-emojis-to-a-label-and-have)

So, in xaml:

```
  <!-- set BindingContext to MyViewModel -->
  <Label FontFamily="Bootstrap" Text="{Binding StateIconName}" />
```

in your MyViewModel:

```
  public string StateIconName
  {
      get => WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xf282;");
  }
```

5.) To browse available glyphs (icons)

Open the overview page: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/

6.) To find the unicode character code, also referred to as "Unicode HTML Entity"

- Check the name of the icon above in step 5.
- Open the Bootstrap-icons.css file from Github: https://github.com/twbs/icons/blob/main/font/bootstrap-icons.css
- Search for the name of the glyph to find the character code, something like:
  .bi-zoom-in::before { content: "\f62c"; }
- Use this code in xaml like